# how to find referred object in a jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, this

how can i get   **this.V2**   out of the FN scope !?

```
$.fn.myFN = function(X){
  this.V1 = X;
  this.V2 = X+2;
};

$("#foo1").myFN(10);
$("#foo2").myFN(20);

console.log(  $("#foo2").V2  ) // this returned undefined
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do it the way you are asking you need to return `this` from the plugin function

```
$.fn.myFN = function (X) {
    this.V1 = X;
    this.V2 = X + 2;
    return this;
};


$(function () {
    var f1 = $("#foo1").myFN(10).V2,
        f2 = $("#foo2").myFN(20).V2;        

    console.log([f1, f2]) //logs [12,22]    
});
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/yjgfmg2j/)**</kbd>

Comment: you were faster than me...lol....you can also have `var fn2 = $("#foo2").myFN(20);` and try `console.log(fn2.V2)`

Answer (score 0):

Return $(this) which is the current context

```
$.fn.myFN = function (X) {
    $(this).V1 = X;
    $(this).V2 = X + 2;
    return $(this);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use [`.prop`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) to store the value in the DOM element:

```
$.fn.myFN = function(X){
  $this = $(this);
  $this.prop('v1', X);
  $this.prop('v2', X+2);
};

$("#foo1").myFN(10);
$("#foo2").myFN(20);

console.log(  $("#foo2").prop('v2')  ) //=> 22
```